# what this means "notice added" and "post locked"

Tags: discussion, moderators, community-user

It is showing in one of my question that the

`notice added by xyz`

`post locked by xyz`

`notice removed by community`

`post unlocked by community`

what does it mean?

Comment: Seems like a moderator tried to stop you from removing the duplicate notice, but the lock is removed later on.

Comment: The post's edit histrory: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14355168/revisions

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14355168/revisions) for the question (which you can get to by clicking the timestamp of the last edit):

Your question was closed as a duplicate of another question by the consensus of 5 community members. As a result, a "possible duplicate" banner was automatically inserted into the text of your question, at the very top. This automatic stuff all shows up as being done by the Community user.

Then, instead of following the proper protocols for attempting to get a question re-opened, you edited the question and removed this "possible duplicate" notice. Or maybe it wasn't intentional. It looks like you just did a lot of editing back and forth for no apparent reason.

Either way, that caused a moderator (casperOne) to step in and (1) restore the "possible duplicate" banner and (2) lock the question to prevent you from editing it any further. Presumably, either your continued edits had become excessively disruptive, or he received a flag that you were trying to remove the "possible duplicate" banner from a closed question. The "Content dispute" notice is used to indicate this locking that took place. This notice was displayed underneath the question to inform other users that the question was locked and why.

Eventually, locks automatically wear off (well, they don't always, but they can; this is at the discretion of the moderator who initially applies them). That's what happened in your case, and the Community user (remember, he's the one who does automatic stuff) unlocked the post and removed the "Content dispute" lock notice.

Comment: Much more detailed answer than mine! Dang phone keyboard!

Comment: ok, then how i can tell that my question is not a duplicate?

Comment: @user20044033 if you think it's not a dupe flag it, choose "Other" and explain why it's not a dupe. Moderator will see it and if he will be convinced, he will reopen your question.

Comment: Use the "edit" link to provide your explanation. Just leave the "possible duplicate" banner there. It will be automatically removed when the question gets re-opened. Either a moderator or 5 community members can re-open a closed question (same as can close one).